# Java: Collecting input with multiple variable types on a single line

Tags: java

How do I collect 4 variables of different types (string, float and integer) of input on a single line like this: (string, float, float, int)?

For example:

```
"joey" 17.4 39.9 6
```

This is what my code looks like now. It works but it only collects the variables one line at a time.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmployeePay{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String employeeID = "";
    double hrsWorked;
    double wageRate;
    int deductions;

    System.out.println("Hello Employee! Please input your employee ID, hours worked per week, hourly rate, and deductions: ");
    employeeID = keyboard.nextLine();
    hrsWorked = keyboard.nextFloat();
    wageRate = keyboard.nextFloat();
    deductions = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Do I need to use a `for` loop?

Comment: `keyboard.nextLine();` is your problem. The rest are collected one line at a time only if you hit enter, you can collect them on one line.

Comment: How would I make it so that I don't need to click enter and all of them just go on the same line?

Comment: How would your program know that you finished entering the input without hitting enter?

Comment: I don't know... Is there a way to make the program know that each space separates a different variable in the input?

Comment: In a way it does, how will it know that you finished entering `6` and that it's not `636`?

Comment: Is there a way I can use .split? Like making it know they're separate by splitting it by the spaces?

Comment: Sure but why? `Scanner` already does it for you. just replace `keyboard.nextLine();` with `keyboard.next();` put them all on one line and hit enter.

Comment: OMG!!! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
employeeID = keyboard.nextLine();
```

to

```
employeeID = keyboard.next();
```

People can now enter the input with spaces inbetween or by using enter each time.

You may also have to change the println statement to a print statement. println sometimes throws off the Scanner class when theres more than one item to collect.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println( " enter i/p ");
    while (scan.hasNext()) { // This will loop your i/p.
        if (scan.hasNextInt()) { // if i/p int 
            System.out.println(" Int " + scan.nextInt());
        } else if (scan.hasNextFloat()) { // if i/p float
            System.out.println(" Float " + scan.nextFloat());
        } 
        else { // if i/p String
            System.out.println( " String " + scan.next());
        }
    }
}
```